# Cannot find the path for used header in new project with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I recently used opencv for my C++ programs. I followed the steps of the tutorial which is about setting the path for opencv.
The header files and functions all worked in my first project.(It's needed to set configurations in an empty project)
However, when I am to create a new project, the compiler cannot find the headers and files of opencv. Should I set all stuff again for a new project?
Or is there any other method to help?
Thank you very much.

Comment: you have to set the information for each new project!

Comment: Visual Studio settings are per project, not system-wide. Create an empty project with all your opencv settings. Copy that project when you start a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio settings are per project, they do not transfer over to different projects.

Set them again.